# CloudKit Error Differentiation

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, nserror

I need some help to learn how to properly handle errors when fetching records via `CloudKit`.  Currently I have an app that saves numerous records in the cloud, and will load them at launch.  I have been referencing the records using a `CKReference`, and anytime I save the reference I use the `CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf` option.  A problem I've encountered periodically is that when a referenced record is deleted, sometimes there can be a significant amount of time before the reference deletes itself. This has caused me to occasionally come across the situation where my app has fetched a `CKReference` for a record that no longer exists.  I'm able to manually find out when this happens just by inserting `print(error!)` in my error handler. What I would like to know is how I can add some code to detect this specific error i.e. `if error.localizedDescription == ??? {`.
Here is the basic code I'm using for the fetch:

```
let fetch = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
fetch.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record:CKRecord?, recordID:CKRecordID?, error: NSError?) in

     if error != nil {

         // Error Line A (See below)
         print("ERROR! : \(error!.localizedDescription)")

         // Error Line B (See below)
         print("ERROR: \(error!)")

     }

     else if let record = record {

         // Record was found
     }
}
if let database = self.privateDatabase {
    fetch.database = database 
    fetch.start()
}
```

And then when it tries to fetch the non-existent record, here is the error message that prints out in the compiler window:

a) `ERROR! : Error fetching record <CKRecordID: 0x10025b290; dbbda7c3-adcc-4271-848f-6702160ea34f:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> from server: Record not found`

b) `ERROR: <CKError 0x125e82820: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "Record not found"; uuid = (removed); container ID = "(removed)">`

Above in error line B, where it says `CKError 0x125e82820:`, can I use this to create an if statement to check for this specific error type?  I really could use any help finding a way to resolve this issue properly when it happens.  I have set up some loading structure for my app, and when it thinks there is a record it needs to find, but can't, it screws up my loading process.  I would really appreciate any help I can get, I assume it's an easy solution, but apparently not one I've been able to find.  Thank you!

**UPDATE -**

Thanks to @AaronBrager, I was able to find the correct solution.  You can verify the error code to match it to any specific error, and the domain to make sure it's a `CKError`.  Here is the solution that works for me:

```
let fetch = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
fetch.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record:CKRecord?, recordID:CKRecordID?, error: NSError?) in

    if error != nil {

        if error!.code == CKErrorCode.UnknownItem.rawValue && error!.domain == CKErrorDomain {

            // This works great!

        }

    }

    else if let record = record {

        // Record was found

    }
}
if let database = self.publicDatabase {
    fetch.database = database
    fetch.start()
}
```

Comment: You should be able to uniquely identify an error's cause by inspecting its `domain` and `code` variables. Same `domain` and `code`, same problem. And unlike `localizedDescription`, it won't change between users.

Comment: So I should be able to always identify the same error if I just add some logic like: `if error.code == CKErrorCode.UnknownItem` ?  I'll test it out.  Thanks

Comment: You should test the code _and the domain_ because the error object might not be a CloudKit error.

Comment: @AarronBrager Thank you for  your quick response.  I just found that by testing the code, that half works great.  I did have to make sure to add the `.rawValue` to the end, so `if error.code == CKErrorCode.UnkownItem.rawValue`.  I'm not quite sure how to write the logic to test the domain.  Would you mind posting an answer so that I can accept it as the correct one?

Comment: Actually I just figured out checking the domain is quite easy.  I will post an update, but if you would like to submit an answer I will accept your's as being correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to uniquely identify an error's cause by inspecting its `domain` and `code` variables. Same `domain` and `code`, same problem. And unlike `localizedDescription`, it won't change between users.